# LINQ exclusion

Tags: sql, linq

Is there a direct LINQ syntax for finding the members of set A that are absent from set B? In SQL I would write this

```
SELECT A.* FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ID WHERE B.ID IS NULL
```

Comment: You meant LEFT OUTER JOIN, I suppose?

Comment: Yes. OUTER is pure syntactic sugar and is optional (qv SQL-92).

Comment: Right. I'm just used to Oracle (+) syntax.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See the MSDN documentation on the [Except operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb300779%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: That's the first time I've had an answer that was complete, directly applicable and effective.

Answer (score 3):

I believe your LINQ would be something like the following.

```
var items = A.Except(
  from itemA in A
  from itemB in B
  where itemA.ID == itemB.ID
  select itemA);
```

#### Update

As indicated by [Maslow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/57883/maslow) in the comments, this may well not be the most performant query. As with any code, it is important to carry out some level of profiling to remove bottlenecks and inefficient algorithms. In this case, [chaowman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507478/linq-exclusion/507605#507605) provides a better performing result.

The reasons can be seen with a little examination of the queries. In the example I provided, there are at least two loops over the A collection - 1 to combine the A and B list, and the other to perform the `Except` operation - whereas in [chaowman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507478/linq-exclusion/507605#507605) (reproduced below), the A collection is only iterated once.

```
// chaowman's solution only iterates A once and partially iterates B
var results = from itemA in A
              where !B.Any(itemB => itemB.Id == itemA.Id)
              select itemA;
```

Also, in my answer, the B collection is iterated in its entirety for every item in A, whereas in [chaowman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507478/linq-exclusion/507605#507605), it is only iterated upto the point at which a match is found.

As you can see, even before looking at the SQL generated, you can spot potential performance issues just from the query itself. Thanks again to [Maslow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/57883/maslow) for highlighting this.

Comment: This LINQ generated an absolutely awful SQL query in LINQPad that took 1 min 17 seconds to run against 2 very large tables. chaowman's took 7.5 seconds. I'd check the efficiency of each of these answers before implementing them large scale.

Comment: @Maslow: You are right, there is no doubt that queries need to be profiled and optimized like any other piece of code, but it's important to get it working first and then optimize. Before you actually profiled these, would you really know which one was going to perform better.

Comment: yes, and it certainly could be a lack of keys in this legacy database.

Answer (score 3):

```
var results = from itemA in A
              where !B.Any(itemB => itemB.Id == itemA.Id)
              select itemA;
```

Comment: This query ran in 7.5 seconds against 2 large tables and generated a nice where not exists query.

Comment: where is ItemB instantiated?